# Java hangin and crashing on centos 6

Tags: centos, vps, java

I'm having problems with running java programs on my VPS.

symptoms:

- Starts and runs for a bit and then just hangs there without any cpu
  use. Usually has different amounts of memory allocated.
- Shows error while starting with both java and javac
- Actually runs. Happens very rarely and usually hangs
- Gives a fatal error has been detected with log file

**startup error**

```
Exception in thread "Reference Handler" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
at java.lang.Object.notifyAll(Native Method)
at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.enqueue(ReferenceQueue.java:68)
at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:146)
```

**hs_err_pid1687.log**

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  Internal Error (synchronizer.cpp:1429), pid=1687, tid=140415983912704
#  guarantee(mid->header()->is_neutral()) failed: invariant
#
# JRE version: 7.0_04-b20
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (23.0-b21 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Core dump written. Default location: /tmp/core or core.1687
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00007fb528086000):  VMThread [stack: 0x00007fb524c78000,0x00007fb524d79000] [id=1689]

Stack: [0x00007fb524c78000,0x00007fb524d79000],  sp=0x00007fb524d77530,  free space=1021k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [libjvm.so+0x8a034a]  VMError::report_and_die()+0x2ea
V  [libjvm.so+0x408f02]  report_vm_error(char const*, int, char const*, char const*)+0x62
V  [libjvm.so+0x825b48]  ObjectSynchronizer::deflate_monitor(ObjectMonitor*, oopDesc*, ObjectMonitor**, ObjectMonitor**)+0xb8
V  [libjvm.so+0x82651e]  ObjectSynchronizer::deflate_idle_monitors()+0x3ae
V  [libjvm.so+0x7c48f7]  SafepointSynchronize::do_cleanup_tasks()+0x37
V  [libjvm.so+0x7c54a2]  SafepointSynchronize::begin()+0x3f2
V  [libjvm.so+0x8a8227]  VMThread::loop()+0x1d7
V  [libjvm.so+0x8a88d0]  VMThread::run()+0x70
V  [libjvm.so+0x741ff0]  java_start(Thread*)+0x100

VM_Operation (0x00007fb511559560): Exit, mode: safepoint, requested by thread 0x00007fb50c001000


---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x00007fb50c001000 JavaThread "SIGINT handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1702, stack(0x00007fb51145a000,0x00007fb51155b000)]
  0x00007fb52816c800 JavaThread "Thread-1" [_thread_blocked, id=1699, stack(0x00007fb51206e000,0x00007fb51216f000)]
  0x00007fb528131000 JavaThread "Java2D Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1697, stack(0x00007fb524098000,0x00007fb524199000)]
  0x00007fb5280e1000 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1695, stack(0x00007fb524773000,0x00007fb524874000)]
  0x00007fb5280de000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1694, stack(0x00007fb524874000,0x00007fb524975000)]
  0x00007fb5280dc000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1693, stack(0x00007fb50a06e000,0x00007fb50a16f000)]
  0x00007fb528090000 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1691, stack(0x00007fb524a76000,0x00007fb524b77000)]
  0x00007fb52808d800 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1690, stack(0x00007fb524b77000,0x00007fb524c78000)]
  0x00007fb528007800 JavaThread "main" [_thread_blocked, id=1688, stack(0x00007fb52e5e3000,0x00007fb52e6e4000)]

Other Threads:
=>0x00007fb528086000 VMThread [stack: 0x00007fb524c78000,0x00007fb524d79000] [id=1689]

VM state:at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread:  ([mutex/lock_event])
[0x00007fb528004ea0] Safepoint_lock - owner thread: 0x00007fb528086000
[0x00007fb528004f20] Threads_lock - owner thread: 0x00007fb528086000

Heap
 def new generation   total 21632K, used 1523K [0x00000000eae00000, 0x00000000ec570000, 0x00000000f0350000)
  eden space 19264K,   7% used [0x00000000eae00000, 0x00000000eaf7c118, 0x00000000ec0d0000)
  from space 2368K,   0% used [0x00000000ec320000, 0x00000000ec320cf0, 0x00000000ec570000)
  to   space 2368K,   0% used [0x00000000ec0d0000, 0x00000000ec0d0000, 0x00000000ec320000)
 tenured generation   total 47856K, used 28711K [0x00000000f0350000, 0x00000000f320c000, 0x00000000fae00000)
   the space 47856K,  59% used [0x00000000f0350000, 0x00000000f1f59ce8, 0x00000000f1f59e00, 0x00000000f320c000)
 compacting perm gen  total 21248K, used 6165K [0x00000000fae00000, 0x00000000fc2c0000, 0x0000000100000000)
   the space 21248K,  29% used [0x00000000fae00000, 0x00000000fb405778, 0x00000000fb405800, 0x00000000fc2c0000)
No shared spaces configured.

Code Cache  [0x00007fb525000000, 0x00007fb525270000, 0x00007fb528000000)
 total_blobs=501 nmethods=156 adapters=297 free_code_cache=48372Kb largest_free_block=49507072

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 4.050 Thread 0x00007fb5280de000 nmethod 151 0x00007fb5250c2b10 code [0x00007fb5250c2c40, 0x00007fb5250c2c98]
Event: 4.050 Thread 0x00007fb5280de000  152             java.awt.Color::getGreen (12 bytes)
Event: 4.050 Thread 0x00007fb5280de000 nmethod 152 0x00007fb5250c2910 code [0x00007fb5250c2a40, 0x00007fb5250c2a98]
Event: 4.050 Thread 0x00007fb5280de000  153             java.awt.Color::getBlue (11 bytes)
Event: 4.051 Thread 0x00007fb5280de000 nmethod 153 0x00007fb5250c2710 code [0x00007fb5250c2840, 0x00007fb5250c2898]
Event: 4.051 Thread 0x00007fb5280de000  154             Start::mate (141 bytes)
Event: 4.051 Thread 0x00007fb5280dc000 nmethod 150 0x00007fb525074ed0 code [0x00007fb525075020, 0x00007fb525075178]
Event: 4.066 Thread 0x00007fb5280de000 nmethod 154 0x00007fb5250c7d10 code [0x00007fb5250c7f40, 0x00007fb5250c8a30]
Event: 4.626 Thread 0x00007fb5280dc000  155             java.awt.image.PackedColorModel::DecomposeMask (147 bytes)
Event: 4.628 Thread 0x00007fb5280dc000 nmethod 155 0x00007fb5250b7590 code [0x00007fb5250b7720, 0x00007fb5250b7978]

GC Heap History (10 events):
Event: 4.603 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=68 (full 3):
 def new generation   total 21632K, used 19618K [0x00000000eae00000, 0x00000000ec570000, 0x00000000f0350000)
  eden space 19264K, 100% used [0x00000000eae00000, 0x00000000ec0d0000, 0x00000000ec0d0000)
  from space 2368K,  14% used [0x00000000ec0d0000, 0x00000000ec128990, 0x00000000ec320000)
  to   space 2368K,   0% used [0x00000000ec320000, 0x00000000ec320000, 0x00000000ec570000)
 tenured generation   total 47856K, used 28711K [0x00000000f0350000, 0x00000000f320c000, 0x00000000fae00000)
   the space 47856K,  59% used [0x00000000f0350000, 0x00000000f1f59ce8, 0x00000000f1f59e00, 0x00000000f320c000)
 compacting perm gen  total 21248K, used 6156K [0x00000000fae00000, 0x00000000fc2c0000, 0x0000000100000000)
   the space 21248K,  28% used [0x00000000fae00000, 0x00000000fb4032e0, 0x00000000fb403400, 0x00000000fc2c0000)
No shared spaces configured.
Event: 4.603 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=69 (full 3):
 def new generation   total 21632K, used 2K [0x00000000eae00000, 0x00000000ec570000, 0x00000000f0350000)
  eden space 19264K,   0% used [0x00000000eae00000, 0x00000000eae00000, 0x00000000ec0d0000)
  from space 2368K,   0% used [0x00000000ec320000, 0x00000000ec320a80, 0x00000000ec570000)
  to   space 2368K,   0% used [0x00000000ec0d0000, 0x00000000ec0d0000, 0x00000000ec320000)
 tenured generation   total 47856K, used 28711K [0x00000000f0350000, 0x00000000f320c000, 0x00000000fae00000)
   the space 47856K,  59% used [0x00000000f0350000, 0x00000000f1f59ce8, 0x00000000f1f59e00, 0x00000000f320c000)
 compacting perm gen  total 21248K, used 6156K [0x00000000fae00000, 0x00000000fc2c0000, 0x0000000100000000)
   the space 21248K,  28% used [0x00000000fae00000, 0x00000000fb4032e0, 0x00000000fb403400, 0x00000000fc2c0000)
No shared spaces configured.
}
Event: 4.645 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=69 (full 3):
 def new generation   total 21632K, used 19266K [0x00000000eae00000, 0x00000000ec570000, 0x00000000f0350000)
  eden space 19264K, 100% used [0x00000000eae00000, 0x00000000ec0d0000, 0x00000000ec0d0000)
  from space 2368K,   0% used [0x00000000ec320000, 0x00000000ec320a80, 0x00000000ec570000)
  to   space 2368K,   0% used [0x00000000ec0d0000, 0x00000000ec0d0000, 0x00000000ec320000)
 tenured generation   total 47856K, used 28711K [0x00000000f0350000, 0x00000000f320c000, 0x00000000fae00000)
   the space 47856K,  59% used [0x00000000f0350000, 0x00000000f1f59ce8, 0x00000000f1f59e00, 0x00000000f320c000)
 compacting perm gen  total 21248K, used 6156K [0x00000000fae00000, 0x00000000fc2c0000, 0x0000000100000000)
   the space 21248K,  28% used [0x00000000fae00000, 0x00000000fb4032e0, 0x00000000fb403400, 0x00000000fc2c0000)
No shared spaces configured.
Event: 4.645 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=70 (full 3):
 def new generation   total 21632K, used 354K [0x00000000eae00000, 0x00000000ec570000, 0x00000000f0350000)
  eden space 19264K,   0% used [0x00000000eae00000, 0x00000000eae00000, 0x00000000ec0d0000)
  from space 2368K,  14% used [0x00000000ec0d0000, 0x00000000ec128ac8, 0x00000000ec320000)
  to   space 2368K,   0% used [0x00000000ec320000, 0x00000000ec320000, 0x00000000ec570000)
 tenured generation   total 47856K, used 28711K [0x00000000f0350000, 0x00000000f320c000, 0x00000000fae00000)
   the space 47856K,  59% used [0x00000000f0350000, 0x00000000f1f59ce8, 0x00000000f1f59e00, 0x00000000f320c000)
 compacting perm gen  total 21248K, used 6156K [0x00000000fae00000, 0x00000000fc2c0000, 0x0000000100000000)
   the space 21248K,  28% used [0x00000000fae00000, 0x00000000fb4032e0, 0x00000000fb403400, 0x00000000fc2c0000)
No shared spaces configured.
}
Event: 4.681 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=70 (full 3):
 def new generation   total 21632K, used 19618K [0x00000000eae00000, 0x00000000ec570000, 0x00000000f0350000)
  eden space 19264K, 100% used [0x00000000eae00000, 0x00000000ec0d0000, 0x00000000ec0d0000)
  from space 2368K,  14% used [0x00000000ec0d0000, 0x00000000ec128ac8, 0x00000000ec320000)
  to   space 2368K,   0% used [0x00000000ec320000, 0x00000000ec320000, 0x00000000ec570000)
 tenured generation   total 47856K, used 28711K [0x00000000f0350000, 0x00000000f320c000, 0x00000000fae00000)
   the space 47856K,  59% used [0x00000000f0350000, 0x00000000f1f59ce8, 0x00000000f1f59e00, 0x00000000f320c000)
 compacting perm gen  total 21248K, used 6156K [0x00000000fae00000, 0x00000000fc2c0000, 0x0000000100000000)
   the space 21248K,  28% used [0x00000000fae00000, 0x00000000fb4032e0, 0x00000000fb403400, 0x00000000fc2c0000)
No shared spaces configured.
Event: 4.682 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=71 (full 3):
 def new generation   total 21632K, used 2K [0x00000000eae00000, 0x00000000ec570000, 0x00000000f0350000)
  eden space 19264K,   0% used [0x00000000eae00000, 0x00000000eae00000, 0x00000000ec0d0000)
  from space 2368K,   0% used [0x00000000ec320000, 0x00000000ec320bb8, 0x00000000ec570000)
  to   space 2368K,   0% used [0x00000000ec0d0000, 0x00000000ec0d0000, 0x00000000ec320000)
 tenured generation   total 47856K, used 28711K [0x00000000f0350000, 0x00000000f320c000, 0x00000000fae00000)
   the space 47856K,  59% used [0x00000000f0350000, 0x00000000f1f59ce8, 0x00000000f1f59e00, 0x00000000f320c000)
 compacting perm gen  total 21248K, used 6156K [0x00000000fae00000, 0x00000000fc2c0000, 0x0000000100000000)
   the space 21248K,  28% used [0x00000000fae00000, 0x00000000fb4032e0, 0x00000000fb403400, 0x00000000fc2c0000)
No shared spaces configured.
}
Event: 4.718 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=71 (full 3):
 def new generation   total 21632K, used 19266K [0x00000000eae00000, 0x00000000ec570000, 0x00000000f0350000)
  eden space 19264K, 100% used [0x00000000eae00000, 0x00000000ec0d0000, 0x00000000ec0d0000)
  from space 2368K,   0% used [0x00000000ec320000, 0x00000000ec320bb8, 0x00000000ec570000)
  to   space 2368K,   0% used [0x00000000ec0d0000, 0x00000000ec0d0000, 0x00000000ec320000)
 tenured generation   total 47856K, used 28711K [0x00000000f0350000, 0x00000000f320c000, 0x00000000fae00000)
   the space 47856K,  59% used [0x00000000f0350000, 0x00000000f1f59ce8, 0x00000000f1f59e00, 0x00000000f320c000)
 compacting perm gen  total 21248K, used 6156K [0x00000000fae00000, 0x00000000fc2c0000, 0x0000000100000000)
   the space 21248K,  28% used [0x00000000fae00000, 0x00000000fb4032e0, 0x00000000fb403400, 0x00000000fc2c0000)
No shared spaces configured.
Event: 4.719 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=72 (full 3):
 def new generation   total 21632K, used 355K [0x00000000eae00000, 0x00000000ec570000, 0x00000000f0350000)
  eden space 19264K,   0% used [0x00000000eae00000, 0x00000000eae00000, 0x00000000ec0d0000)
  from space 2368K,  14% used [0x00000000ec0d0000, 0x00000000ec128c00, 0x00000000ec320000)
  to   space 2368K,   0% used [0x00000000ec320000, 0x00000000ec320000, 0x00000000ec570000)
 tenured generation   total 47856K, used 28711K [0x00000000f0350000, 0x00000000f320c000, 0x00000000fae00000)
   the space 47856K,  59% used [0x00000000f0350000, 0x00000000f1f59ce8, 0x00000000f1f59e00, 0x00000000f320c000)
 compacting perm gen  total 21248K, used 6156K [0x00000000fae00000, 0x00000000fc2c0000, 0x0000000100000000)
   the space 21248K,  28% used [0x00000000fae00000, 0x00000000fb4032e0, 0x00000000fb403400, 0x00000000fc2c0000)
No shared spaces configured.
}
Event: 4.762 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=72 (full 3):
 def new generation   total 21632K, used 19553K [0x00000000eae00000, 0x00000000ec570000, 0x00000000f0350000)
  eden space 19264K,  99% used [0x00000000eae00000, 0x00000000ec0bfb08, 0x00000000ec0d0000)
  from space 2368K,  14% used [0x00000000ec0d0000, 0x00000000ec128c00, 0x00000000ec320000)
  to   space 2368K,   0% used [0x00000000ec320000, 0x00000000ec320000, 0x00000000ec570000)
 tenured generation   total 47856K, used 28711K [0x00000000f0350000, 0x00000000f320c000, 0x00000000fae00000)
   the space 47856K,  59% used [0x00000000f0350000, 0x00000000f1f59ce8, 0x00000000f1f59e00, 0x00000000f320c000)
 compacting perm gen  total 21248K, used 6156K [0x00000000fae00000, 0x00000000fc2c0000, 0x0000000100000000)
   the space 21248K,  28% used [0x00000000fae00000, 0x00000000fb4032e0, 0x00000000fb403400, 0x00000000fc2c0000)
No shared spaces configured.
Event: 4.763 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=73 (full 3):
 def new generation   total 21632K, used 3K [0x00000000eae00000, 0x00000000ec570000, 0x00000000f0350000)
  eden space 19264K,   0% used [0x00000000eae00000, 0x00000000eae00000, 0x00000000ec0d0000)
  from space 2368K,   0% used [0x00000000ec320000, 0x00000000ec320cf0, 0x00000000ec570000)
  to   space 2368K,   0% used [0x00000000ec0d0000, 0x00000000ec0d0000, 0x00000000ec320000)
 tenured generation   total 47856K, used 28711K [0x00000000f0350000, 0x00000000f320c000, 0x00000000fae00000)
   the space 47856K,  59% used [0x00000000f0350000, 0x00000000f1f59ce8, 0x00000000f1f59e00, 0x00000000f320c000)
 compacting perm gen  total 21248K, used 6156K [0x00000000fae00000, 0x00000000fc2c0000, 0x0000000100000000)
   the space 21248K,  28% used [0x00000000fae00000, 0x00000000fb4032e0, 0x00000000fb403400, 0x00000000fc2c0000)
No shared spaces configured.
}

Deoptimization events (7 events):
Event: 1.048 Thread 0x00007fb528140000 Uncommon trap -34 fr.pc 0x00007fb52507303c
Event: 1.048 Thread 0x00007fb528140000 Uncommon trap -34 fr.pc 0x00007fb52507303c
Event: 1.048 Thread 0x00007fb528140000 Uncommon trap -34 fr.pc 0x00007fb52507303c
Event: 1.048 Thread 0x00007fb528140000 Uncommon trap -34 fr.pc 0x00007fb52507303c
Event: 1.066 Thread 0x00007fb528140000 Uncommon trap -28 fr.pc 0x00007fb52509490c
Event: 1.071 Thread 0x00007fb528140000 Uncommon trap -28 fr.pc 0x00007fb52509771c
Event: 1.220 Thread 0x00007fb528140000 Uncommon trap 132 fr.pc 0x00007fb525091104

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 0.079 Thread 0x00007fb528007800 Threw 0x00000000eae66e08 at /HUDSON/workspace/jdk7u4-2-build-linux-amd64-product/jdk7u4/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp:1166
Event: 0.079 Thread 0x00007fb528007800 Threw 0x00000000eae66f30 at /HUDSON/workspace/jdk7u4-2-build-linux-amd64-product/jdk7u4/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp:1166
Event: 0.079 Thread 0x00007fb528007800 Threw 0x00000000eae68cd8 at /HUDSON/workspace/jdk7u4-2-build-linux-amd64-product/jdk7u4/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp:1166
Event: 0.079 Thread 0x00007fb528007800 Threw 0x00000000eae68e00 at /HUDSON/workspace/jdk7u4-2-build-linux-amd64-product/jdk7u4/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp:1166
Event: 0.124 Thread 0x00007fb528007800 Threw 0x00000000eae83ce0 at /HUDSON/workspace/jdk7u4-2-build-linux-amd64-product/jdk7u4/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp:715
Event: 0.124 Thread 0x00007fb528007800 Threw 0x00000000eae84518 at /HUDSON/workspace/jdk7u4-2-build-linux-amd64-product/jdk7u4/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp:715
Event: 0.152 Thread 0x00007fb528007800 Threw 0x00000000eaf3a318 at /HUDSON/workspace/jdk7u4-2-build-linux-amd64-product/jdk7u4/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp:1166
Event: 0.344 Thread 0x00007fb528007800 Threw 0x00000000eaf92118 at /HUDSON/workspace/jdk7u4-2-build-linux-amd64-product/jdk7u4/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp:1166
Event: 0.355 Thread 0x00007fb528007800 Threw 0x00000000eafa9160 at /HUDSON/workspace/jdk7u4-2-build-linux-amd64-product/jdk7u4/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp:1166
Event: 0.625 Thread 0x00007fb528007800 Threw 0x00000000eb364988 at /HUDSON/workspace/jdk7u4-2-build-linux-amd64-product/jdk7u4/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp:1166

Events (10 events):
Event: 4.763 Executing VM operation: GenCollectForAllocation done
Event: 94.007 loading class 0x00007fb5280c15a0
Event: 94.126 loading class 0x00007fb5280c15a0 done
Event: 94.126 Thread 0x00007fb50c001000 Thread added: 0x00007fb50c001000
Event: 94.126 loading class 0x00007fb528021780
Event: 94.126 loading class 0x00007fb528021780 done
Event: 94.126 loading class 0x00007fb504045d40
Event: 94.126 loading class 0x00007fb504045d40 done
Event: 94.127 Thread 0x00007fb5280d9800 Thread exited: 0x00007fb5280d9800
Event: 94.127 Executing VM operation: Exit


Dynamic libraries:
00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 90:77 251104202                          /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_04/bin/java
00600000-00601000 rw-p 00000000 90:77 251104202                          /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_04/bin/java
00601000-00622000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
eae00000-ec570000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
ec570000-f0350000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
f0350000-f320c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
f320c000-fae00000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
fae00000-fc2c0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
fc2c0000-100000000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fb4fc000000-7fb4fc54f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fb4fc54f000-7fb500000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fb500000000-7fb500021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fb500021000-7fb504000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fb504000000-7fb504437000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fb504437000-7fb508000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fb50a06e000-7fb50a071000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fb50a071000-7fb50a16f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fb50c000000-7fb50c021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fb50c021000-7fb510000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fb511264000-7fb51145a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fb51145a000-7fb51145d000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fb51145d000-7fb51155b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0         /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_04/jre/lib/amd64/libnet.so
7fb511bff000-7fb511c00000 rw-p 00015000 90:77 251106756                  /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_04/jre/lib/amd64/libnet.so
7fb511c00000-7fb511c16000 r-xp 00000000 90:77 251068820                  /lib64/libgcc_s-4.4.6-20110824.so.1
7fb511c16000-7fb511e15000 ---p 00016000 90:77 251068820                  /lib64/libgcc_s-4.4.6-20110824.so.1
7fb511e15000-7fb511e16000 rw-p 00015000 90:77 251068820                  /lib64/libgcc_s-4.4.6-20110824.so.1
7fb511e16000-7fb511e5a000 r-xp 00000000 90:77 251106748                  /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_04/jre/lib/amd64/libfontmanager.so
7fb511e5a000-7fb51205a000 ---p 00044000 90:77 251106748                  /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_04/jre/lib/amd64/libfontmanager.so
7fb51205a000-7fb51205e000 rw-p 00044000 90:77 251106748                  /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_04/jre/lib/amd64/libfontmanager.so
7fb51205e000-7fb51206e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fb51206e000-7fb512071000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fb512071000-7fb51216f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fb51216f000-7fb518000000 r--p 00000000 90:77 5175065                    /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive-rpm
7fb518000000-7fb518021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fb518021000-7fb51c000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fb51c000000-7fb51c021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fb51c021000-7fb520000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fb520000000-7fb52042f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fb52042f000-7fb524000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fb524098000-7fb52409b000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fb52409b000-7fb524199000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fb524199000-7fb52419f000 r-xp 00000000 90:77 251106834                  /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_04/jre/lib/amd64/headless/libmawt.so
7fb52419f000-7fb52439f000 ---p 00006000 90:77 251106834                  /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_04/jre/lib/amd64/headless/libmawt.so
7fb52439f000-7fb5243a0000 rw-p 00006000 90:77 251106834                  /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_04/jre/lib/amd64/headless/libmawt.so
7fb5243a0000-7fb524442000 r-xp 00000000 90:77 251106770                  /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_04/jre/lib/amd64/libawt.so
7fb524442000-7fb524642000 ---p 000a2000 90:77 251106770                  /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_04/jre/lib/amd64/libawt.so
7fb524642000-7fb52464e000 rw-p 000a2000 90:77 251106770                  /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_04/jre/lib/amd64/libawt.so
7fb52464e000-7fb524672000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fb524672000-7fb524673000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fb524673000-7fb524773000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fb524dea000-7fb524faa000 r--s 03a2e000 90:77 251106852                  /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_04/jre/lib/rt.jar
7fb524faa000-7fb524fc2000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fb524fc2000-7fb525000000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fb525000000-7fb525270000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7fb52c0f9000-7fb52c0fa000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fb52c0fa000-7fb52c114000 r-xp 00000000 90:77 251106830                  /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_04/jre/lib/amd64/libzip.so
7fb52c114000-7fb52c314000 ---p 0001a000 90:77 251106830                  /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_04/jre/lib/amd64/libzip.so
7fb52c314000-7fb52c315000 rw-p 0001a000 90:77 251106830                  /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_04/jre/lib/amd64/libzip.so
7fb52c315000-7fb52c321000 r-xp 00000000 90:77 251068694                  /lib64/libnss_files-2.12.so
7fb52c321000-7fb52c521000 ---p 0000c000 90:77 251068694                  /lib64/libnss_files-2.12.so
7fb52c521000-7fb52c522000 r--p 0000c000 90:77 251068694                  /lib64/libnss_files-2.12.so
7fb52c522000-7fb52c523000 rw-p 0000d000 90:77 251068694                  /lib64/libnss_files-2.12.so
7fb52c523000-7fb52c54c000 r-xp 00000000 90:77 251106806                  /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_04/jre/lib/amd64/libjava.so
7fb52c54c000-7fb52c74c000 ---p 00029000 90:77 251106806                  /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_04/jre/lib/amd64/libjava.so
7fb52c74c000-7fb52c74e000 rw-p 00029000 90:77 251106806                  /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_04/jre/lib/amd64/libjava.so
7fb52c74e000-7fb52c75d000 r-xp 00000000 90:77 251106802                  /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_04/jre/lib/amd64/libverify.so
7fb52c75d000-7fb52c95c000 ---p 0000f000 90:77 251106802                  /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_04/jre/lib/amd64/libverify.so
7fb52c95c000-7fb52c95e000 rw-p 0000e000 90:77 251106802                  /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_04/jre/lib/amd64/libverify.so
7fb52cdea000-7fb52d82b000 r-xp 00000000 90:77 251106816                  /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_04/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
7fb52d82b000-7fb52da2a000 ---p 00a41000 90:77 251106816                  /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_04/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
7fb52da2a000-7fb52dace000 rw-p 00a40000 90:77 251106816                  /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_04/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
7fb52dace000-7fb52db09000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fb52db09000-7fb52dc8f000 r-xp 00000000 90:77 251068766                  /lib64/libc-2.12.so
7fb52dc8f000-7fb52de8f000 ---p 00186000 90:77 251068766                  /lib64/libc-2.12.so
7fb52de8f000-7fb52de93000 r--p 00186000 90:77 251068766                  /lib64/libc-2.12.so
7fb52de93000-7fb52de94000 rw-p 0018a000 90:77 251068766                  /lib64/libc-2.12.so
7fb52de94000-7fb52de99000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fb52de99000-7fb52de9b000 r-xp 00000000 90:77 251068790                  /lib64/libdl-2.12.so
7fb52de9b000-7fb52e09b000 ---p 00002000 90:77 251068790                  /lib64/libdl-2.12.so
7fb52e09b000-7fb52e09c000 r--p 00002000 90:77 251068790                  /lib64/libdl-2.12.so
7fb52e09c000-7fb52e09d000 rw-p 00003000 90:77 251068790                  /lib64/libdl-2.12.so
7fb52e09d000-7fb52e0b3000 r-xp 00000000 90:77 251106766                  /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_04/jre/lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so
7fb52e0b3000-7fb52e2b2000 ---p 00016000 90:77 251106766                  /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_04/jre/lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so
7fb52e2b2000-7fb52e2b3000 rw-p 00015000 90:77 251106766                  /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_04/jre/lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so
7fb52e2b3000-7fb52e2ca000 r-xp 00000000 90:77 251068666                  /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so
7fb52e2ca000-7fb52e4c9000 ---p 00017000 90:77 251068666                  /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so
7fb52e4c9000-7fb52e4ca000 r--p 00016000 90:77 251068666                  /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so
7fb52e4ca000-7fb52e4cb000 rw-p 00017000 90:77 251068666                  /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so
7fb52e4cb000-7fb52e4cf000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fb52e4cf000-7fb52e4ef000 r-xp 00000000 90:77 251070774                  /lib64/ld-2.12.so
7fb52e4f1000-7fb52e4fc000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fb52e4fc000-7fb52e51b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fb52e51b000-7fb52e525000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fb52e525000-7fb52e5db000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fb52e5db000-7fb52e5e3000 rw-s 00000000 90:77 251108404                  /tmp/hsperfdata_root/1687
7fb52e5e3000-7fb52e5e6000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fb52e5e6000-7fb52e6e8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fb52e6ea000-7fb52e6ec000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fb52e6ec000-7fb52e6ed000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fb52e6ed000-7fb52e6ee000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fb52e6ee000-7fb52e6ef000 r--p 0001f000 90:77 251070774                  /lib64/ld-2.12.so
7fb52e6ef000-7fb52e6f0000 rw-p 00020000 90:77 251070774                  /lib64/ld-2.12.so
7fb52e6f0000-7fb52e6f1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fff26a7d000-7fff26a92000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7fff26b3d000-7fff26b3f000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]

VM Arguments:
java_command: Start
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_04
PATH=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_04/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin
SHELL=/bin/bash

Signal Handlers:
SIGSEGV: [libjvm.so+0x8a0cb0], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGBUS: [libjvm.so+0x8a0cb0], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGFPE: [libjvm.so+0x73d630], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGPIPE: [libjvm.so+0x73d630], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGXFSZ: [libjvm.so+0x73d630], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGILL: [libjvm.so+0x73d630], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGUSR1: SIG_DFL, sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x00000000
SIGUSR2: [libjvm.so+0x73cf80], sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGHUP: [libjvm.so+0x73f310], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGINT: [libjvm.so+0x73f310], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGTERM: [libjvm.so+0x73f310], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGQUIT: [libjvm.so+0x73f310], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004


---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS:CentOS release 6.2 (Final)

uname:Linux 2.6.32-042stab053.5 #1 SMP Tue Mar 27 11:42:17 MSD 2012 x86_64
libc:glibc 2.12 NPTL 2.12 
rlimit: STACK 10240k, CORE infinity, NPROC 1024, NOFILE 1024, AS infinity
load average:0.03 0.05 0.01

/proc/meminfo:
MemTotal:        1048576 kB
MemFree:          737060 kB
Cached:
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to the issue. I am getting simpler issue while trying to build shopizer on my VPS.

Comment: Info about what was the proplem with the VPS I tried to use. http://forum.proxmox.com/threads/6998-Best-strategy-to-handle-strange-JVM-errors-inside-VPS

Comment: I observe the same with Java 1.7.0_05-b05 on Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 1):

at a really quick guess, the  'JavaThread "SIGINT handler" daemon"' suggests that it might be your ISP Host killing your processes because you exceeded some resource limit such as threads/processes/RAM/cpu/inodes etc.

There is also the OOM killer, but I suspect that would be logged in the `/var/log/messages` files